# engineer tech support

Tags: untagged

i joined as engineer tech support in Origin infosystems. my qualification is b.e cse 2010 passed out.and i am in chennai. me working now in a client company(tcseserve). they offering package of 5.5k take home. i am scary about my future because not i am worrying about my carrier path. for this job diploma candidates are eligible. i dont know what for i did the b.e. package is also too low. i recently join there. but my coworkers are older people than me. what coworkers is suggesting me is "as you are a fresher you have to move to software job. this field we cant earn more money even we have the experience." i dont know what i have to do.

now what i need to know is if i am moving to the server administration(l2 support) can i earn more money like software developers?
i very much like the server administration than software developing. so what i have to do to get good career growth. what is the certification course i need to do.?
is one year experience as tech support as acceptable in mnc company s?
i think the other sick in this field is only few peoples are in a company are required to maintain the servers in a big company. but more peoples are doing courses related to this career. so what i like to know is really if i follow this career path am i get good profile with good package or not?
or otherwise can i change the carrier path?

please give me your valuable reply for those doubts. and tell me what i have to do for get good growth in this field and how many year of experience are need to get into mnc company s.

thank you,

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that you're pretty young and starting out in your career - if that's the case the what I'm about to say is something I've learnt over the last two decades and something I really wish someone had taught me when I was your age - and it's this; **you should do what you *want* to do.**

The world is full of people who don't enjoy doing their job, but when you meet someone who is very successful at their field it's almost always because the truly love doing it. Passion for an area in life usually leads to competence, then excellence, and depending on the field can also lead to financial and professional benefits too.

I focussed too much on money and prestige when I was younger but what actually brought me these has been focussing on what I love doing - I wake up genuinely happy almost every day simply because I get paid to do what I'm interested in with people I enjoy working alongside. As a result of this my family and friends benefit too.

I can give you no better advice than to spend your time doing things that fill you with joy - everything else will fall into place.

Good luck.

Comment: +1. Good advice for sure. I spent many years chasing the money, doing work that I hated, and was miserable for it. I got interested in computers, began to pursue that, and the money and happiness soon followed. I genuinely enjoy the work that I do... if not always the company that I do it for. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is do what you like, and what you are best at, you'll earn more as a good systems engineer than as a mediocre software developer.

Both have high potential earnings, but you have to be good at it and have a passion for your cvhosen field.